# SCP and rsync upload getting weird group name

Tags: permissions

When I use scp to upload file to server using `scp`:

```
scp -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -i "${rsa_key}" /local/file.txt "me@server:~/"
```

Now when I check this file permission, I got the following:

```
770:-rwxrwx---  root:UNKNOWN file.txt
```

So, now if I use `rsync` like below:

```
rsync -Pav -e "ssh -q -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -i '${rsa_key}'" /local/file.txt "me@server:~/"
```

And when I check the file permission, I got the following with the group name `gotify`:

```
770:-rwxrwx---  root:gotify file.txt
```

Now, I'm getting scared for this last output because the file belongs to the gotify group which I never ever set this. Everytime I use rsync to push file, it will automatically has this group name `gotify`. How do I inspect this, so that maybe someone else has changed it ?

Comment: Nobody changed it. Check the remote `/etc/group` file for `gotify` and look at your local `/etc/group` for which group have the same GID.

Comment: Gotify has the GID 918, and no other user has this GID. Why did rsync use this group name.

Comment: Things getting weird if I remove gotify user and group, and try to upload using rsync again, I got UNKNOWN group. My paranoia starts when rsync suddenly choose the group gotify for file upload and I never set that. So, I reinstall gotify, create username and group of gotify. Now using rsync again, it still got gotify groupname when upload file to a remote server. Does this mean someone has changed something in rsync or is this just a bug in rsync but why does it choose gotify?

Comment: Is the group owner GID 918 on the source machine? That's why.

Comment: The source machine you mean the local machine right. There is none. I started to think that I get compromised. Someone might has gained access into gotify, modified the rsync to have group gotify when pushing files. So anyone who got gotify username would be able to read the file.